# Retrieve default product image without product - Magento

Tags: magento

I would like to retrieve the default product thumbnail in Magento to apply it to something else other than a product, so I don't have access to $product. Would it be possible?

Thanks,
Krt_Malta

Answer (score 0):

Untested but this should work:

```
/**
 * Get the resource model
 */
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');

/**
 * Retrieve the read connection
 */
$readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');

$query = 'SELECT thumbnail FROM ' . $resource->getTableName('catalog/product_flat') . ' WHERE sku = "(insert your product SKU here)"'; // Insert SKU here

/**
 * Execute the query and store the results in $results
 */
$results = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);

/**
 * Print out the results
 */
echo sprintf('<pre>%s</pre>' print_r($results, true));
```